# Hotspot does not allow android to obtain an ip address

Tags: 12.04, wireless, android, hot-spot

I'm using the instructions from

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access.html

and I've tweaked it for infrastructure mode, however my android 4.2.2 device is stuck in an "obtaining ip address loop"

Answer (score 1):

When your Android Device doesn't get an IP it may not be served by one. Please make shure that there is a DHCP Server Process/Deamon running on your PC. Also you should have a look for a DNS Server Process/Deamon.